# How can I select a table for styling without an ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am helping to design a site in Volusion and trying to style a table with no span id. Since the table is automatically generated from Volusion, a span id cannot be added. I went into the CSS and tried everything to no avail. Here is a small snippet of the current code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr class="colors_backgroundlight">
<td>Item#</td>
<td>Item Name</td>
<td><span class="PageText_L335n"><b>Starting at</b></span></td>
<td><span class="PageText_L71n">Qty</span></td>
<td><b><span class="PageText_L337n">Add</span></b></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="Multi-Child_Background">
<td class="smalltext colors_text">NFBM665-S</td>
<td class="productnamecolorSMALL colors_productname">Foil Thermal Bubble Mailer, 6" x 6.5" Sample</td>
```

Unfortunately, there are other tables on the page, so I have no idea what to do. Is there any type of Javascript code that I can use that can just target this specific table? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does the table always fall in a particular location in the page? You could target by index (order), or you could target by a previous sibling that has an ID, or by an ancestor element, or a combination of these.

Comment: Post a representation of the larger HTML document structure for more useful help.

Comment: Here is the page I am currently trying to style the table on: http://qjtrn.cjxgw.servertrust.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=Samples-NFBM

Comment: Can you contain the table inside something you can ID? That is, wrap the Volusion output inside a div you can target?

Comment: @n8wrl Unfortunately, I can't. I can put code above the table, but that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have the same issues isolating the table in JavaScript as you will in CSS.

CSS styles can be applied based on a variety of things besides an `id`. The table's relative position in the DOM (if that is static) would be my next choice.

Based on the DOM in your scenario, you have a `span` element that is a sibling of the `table` that you are after. That `span` has an `id` of `product_description`, which makes it unique within the document. The following would pick up the table as a sibling element that follows the `span`:

```css
#product_description ~ table { background:yellow; }

#product_description ~ table td { padding:25px; }
```

```html
<span id="product_description" itemprop="description">
Please Note: For Thermal Bubble Mailer samples, we charge $5.95 for shipping and handling for each sample.<br />
1 sample per item, per customer. Coupon codes cannot be applied to samples.<br /><hr />
</span>
<br /><br />
<div style='height: 15px;'></div>
<div style='clear: both;'></div>

<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr class="colors_backgroundlight">
    <td>Item#</td>
    <td>Item Name</td>
    <td><span class="PageText_L335n"><b>Starting at</b></span></td>
    <td><span class="PageText_L71n">Qty</span></td>
    <td><b><span class="PageText_L337n">Add</span></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="Multi-Child_Background">
    <td class="smalltext colors_text">NFBM665-S</td>
    <td class="productnamecolorSMALL colors_productname">Foil Thermal Bubble Mailer, 6" x 6.5" Sample</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott. That looks like it's getting somewhere. The top row turned yellow. Is there code I can put in there for padding?

Comment: Sure, but you have to be more specific. Padding for what? The table? The cells in the table, etc.?

Comment: Sorry, padding between the content in the table - EDIT: Item#, Item Name, etc.

Comment: Ok, that's the cell padding. I'll updated my answer with that.

Comment: Of course, this approach is fragile as it relies on that sibling element always being there. I'm not familiar with Volusion, but it's likely that there's a better way to handle this.

Comment: @isherwood Yes, I stated that this solution would work only if the DOM structure was static. But it appears that it is.

Comment: @DanD Just checking your sample at: http://qjtrn.cjxgw.servertrust.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=Samples-NFBM I want to remind you that the CSS rule that turns the table yellow was just to show that we were finding the correct table. That one is not necessary and can be removed if what you are really after is the cells in the table (the second rule).

Comment: @ScottMarcus I got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can go with siblings or parent elements(ancestors) id to project the table in entire html page.

If you are using chrome browser, inspect the table element and then right click to copy selector. And then define your css for this selector. This selector will uniquely define your table throughout your the HTML page.

**Note**: If there are fixed number of tables in that HTML page, it is easy and fast to go with table indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can select an element with its other attributes than id, for example:

```
table[bgcolor="#CCCCCC"]
```

or you can chain more attributes:

```
table[bgcolor="#CCCCCC"][border="0"]
```

Read more: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp